# Install GD library and freetype on Linux

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, gd, freetype

I'm trying to use imagefttext. And I need to have GD library and/or freetype installed.
I'm new to this kind of stuffs, **How can I install GD library and freetype in Linux ?**

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: You should mention that, different Linux distribution use different [package management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system), for example, Fedora/CentOS use 'Yum', Debian/Ubuntu use 'Apt'.

Answer (score 75):

### Installing GD :

For **CentOS / RedHat / Fedora** :

```
sudo yum install php-gd
```

For **Debian/ubuntu** :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

### Installing freetype :

For **CentOS / RedHat / Fedora** :

```
sudo yum install freetype*
```

For **Debian/ubuntu** :

```
sudo apt-get install freetype*
```

---

Don't forget to restart apache after that (if you are using apache):

**CentOS / RedHat / Fedora** :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Or

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

**Debian/ubuntu** :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I'm using ubuntu, so I just tried this with 'sudo apt-get install php5-gd'. However, it says PHP-GD is already the newest version. I'm guessing this means i have the GD library installed, so now I just need to enable Freetype somehow. The php wiki has this "To enable support for FreeType 2 add --with-freetype-dir=DIR ." but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: freetype won't work, it says it is unable to locate package freetype

Comment: Im not using ubunto to test it, but its my first result of search `how to install freetype in ubunto` . you can search too

Comment: write freetype* instead of freetype

Comment: I don't know either, You should ask it from the person who add it on the repository. For all I know It maybe there under the name of "freetype*" instead of "freetype"

Comment: This is why my Wordpress thumbnails weren't being built

Comment: @DaveHilditch - Yes, you have to install it for generating wordpress thumbnails.

Comment: Do you have to activate the module for PHP also?

Comment: @ronnyandre, no, you dont need to

Comment: don't forget to restart apache: sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 14):

Things are pretty much simpler unless they are made confusing.

**To Install GD library in Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

**To Install Freetype in Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev:i386
```

Comment: In 14.04 LTS, installing php5-gd took care of Freetype as well (so only php5-gd needed to be installed).

Comment: `apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` works for me!

Answer (score 2):

**For CentOS:**
When installing php-gd you need to specify the version. I fixed it by running:
**sudo yum install php55-gd**

Comment: I'm on aws linux with PHP Version 5.6.17 `sudo yum install php56-gd` works on my *[site](http://forum.tophyips.info/)*. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Installing freetype:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install freetype2-demos`