# Can't install php-gd and freetype with yum on centos

Tags: php, linux, centos, yum

I'm unable to install GD and Freetype for PHP on centos.

I've read many similar questions like this one [Install GD library and freetype on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216129/install-gd-library-and-freetype-on-linux)
But I'm still having no luck..

```
    [root@media modules]# sudo yum install php-gd
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, replace, security
    Setting up Install Process
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.overthewire.com.au
     * extras: mirror.nsw.coloau.com.au
     * ius: ius.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
     * remi-php56: mirror.innosol.asia
     * rpmforge: mirror.ventraip.net.au
     * updates: mirror.overthewire.com.au
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.20-1.el6.remi will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libvpx.so.1()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package libvpx.x86_64 0:1.3.0-5.el6_5 will be installed
    ---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.20-1.el6.remi will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Requires: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1
    Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Requires: libgd.so.3()(64bit)
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
    sudo apt-get install freetype*[root@media modules]# sudo apt-get install freetype*
    sudo: apt-get: command not found

    [root@media modules]# sudo yum install freetype*
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, replace, security
    Setting up Install Process
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.overthewire.com.au
     * extras: mirror.nsw.coloau.com.au
     * ius: ius.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
     * remi-php56: remi.conetix.com.au
     * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
     * updates: mirror.overthewire.com.au
    Package freetype-2.3.11-15.el6_6.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Package freetype-devel-2.3.11-15.el6_6.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Package freetype-demos-2.3.11-15.el6_6.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Nothing to do

    [root@media modules]# service httpd restart
    Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
    Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]

    [root@media modules]# sudo yum install php56-gd
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, replace, security
    Setting up Install Process
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.overthewire.com.au
     * extras: mirror.nsw.coloau.com.au
     * ius: syd.mirror.rackspace.com
     * remi-php56: remi.conetix.com.au
     * rpmforge: mirror.ventraip.net.au
     * updates: mirror.overthewire.com.au
    No package php56-gd available.
    Error: Nothing to do

[root@media modules]# yum install php-gd --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, replace, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.overthewire.com.au
 * extras: mirror.nsw.coloau.com.au
 * ius: ius.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 * remi-php56: remi.conetix.com.au
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au
 * updates: mirror.overthewire.com.au
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.20-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libvpx.so.1()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libvpx.x86_64 0:1.3.0-5.el6_5 will be installed
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.20-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1
Error: Package: php-gd-5.6.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libgd.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

My web app still shows

```
PHP GD Extension:   Not Found
PHP FreeType Support:   Not Found
```

And I'm pretty confident about this because it work before I uninstalled PHP and installed a different version and lost these extensions :/

Comment: 2 second google: http://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?id=2698

Comment: No, you can see in my question I've tried something like that already.

Comment: You don't appear to have a `remi` repo. Do you see one if you run `yum repolist`? Is freetype support something that can be dynamically loaded the way gd appears to work? I thought it was a compile-time choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and [remi-safe](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/06/02/New-remi-safe-repository-for-EL-7) repositories which provides common dependencies for the various PHP versions available in remi-php55, remi-php56, remi-php70...

remi-safe repository is enabled by default when you install the remi-release configuration package. epel-release is a dependency of remi-release.

The [configuration wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) gives you the correct instructions.

Duplicate of http://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?id=3402

Comment: I suspected it would be something like that!  I just lost track of what came from where after all the advice I found like "disable this conflicting repo, add this repo..." for various things I've done in the last couple days. PS your wizard thing links to a localhost.  Unless that was supposed to link to something on my computer?  I'm puttying to a server from windows.

Comment: Link to configuration wizard fixed.

Comment: I've never seen that configuration wizard before. You rock, Remi!